# ¿Como juntar archivos mp4 y wav en uno solo?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de juntar un un archivo.wav y un archivo.mp4 en uno solo, sin usar la libreria/software ffmpeg, mi codigo recibe 2 strings (ruta de audio, ruta de video), pero tengo un error:

```
Null Pointer Exception en 
audioCoder = containerAudio.getStream(audioStream).getStreamCoder();
```

Mi código:

```
public class Mix 
{
    public CreateDir cd = new CreateDir();
    int nextFile, numStreamAudio, numStreamVideo, audioStream, videoStream, offSet, decodedV, decodedA;
    String path;
    IContainer containerVideo, containerAudio;
    IStreamCoder videoCoder, code, audioCoder;
    IStream stream;
    IPacket packetA, packetV;
    IVideoPicture pic;
    IAudioSamples samples;
    IMediaWriter writer;
    
    public void mergeFiles(String pathAudio, String pathVideo)
    {
        path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        nextFile = cd.createDir("Mix");
        writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(path + "ClientVideos/Video_" + nextFile+"/videowriter.flv");
        
        containerVideo = IContainer.make();
        containerAudio = IContainer.make();
        
        numStreamVideo = containerVideo.getNumStreams();
        numStreamAudio = containerAudio.getNumStreams();
        
        videoStream = -1;
        audioStream = -1;
        videoCoder = null;
        
        streamsCoders();
     
        packetV = IPacket.make();
       **audioCoder = containerAudio.getStream(audioStream).getStreamCoder();**
        writer.addAudioStream(0, 0, audioCoder.getChannels(), audioCoder.getSampleRate());
        writer.addVideoStream(1, 1, videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());
        packetA = IPacket.make();
        
        while(containerVideo.readNextPacket(packetV) >= 0 || containerAudio.readNextPacket(packetA) >= 0)
        {
            if (packetV.getStreamIndex() == videoStream)
            {
                pic = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(), videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());
                offSet = 0;
                
                while(offSet < packetV.getSize())
                {
                    decodedV = videoCoder.decodeVideo(pic, packetV, offSet);
                    if (decodedV < 0) { offSet += decodedV; }
                    
                    if (pic.isComplete()) { writer.encodeVideo(1, pic); }
                }
            }
            
            if(packetA.getStreamIndex() == audioStream)
            {
                samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, audioCoder.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32P);
                offSet = 0;
                
                while(offSet < packetA.getSize())
                {
                    decodedA = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, packetA, offSet);
                    if (decodedA < 0) { offSet += decodedA; }
                    
                    if (samples.isComplete()) { writer.encodeAudio(0, samples); }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public void streamsCoders()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i< numStreamVideo; i++)
            {
                stream = containerVideo.getStream(i);
                code = stream.getStreamCoder();
                
                if (code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
                {
                    videoStream = i;
                    videoCoder = code;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            for(int i=0; i<numStreamAudio; i++)
            {
                stream = containerAudio.getStream(i);
                code = stream.getStreamCoder();

                if(code.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
                {
                    audioStream = i;
                    break;
                }

            }
    }
}
```

**Si hay una manera más eficiente/optima de combinar un mp4 con un wav, espero y pueda darme tips o recomendaciones.**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes llamar archivos de una forma parecida a dato en java, así los unes, aplica el ejemplo a tu gusto

```
public class WrapperExe {

 public boolean doSomething() {

 String[] exeCmd = new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i", "audioInput.mp3", "-i", "videoInput.avi" ,"-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", "outputFile.avi"};

 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exeCmd);
 boolean exeCmdStatus = executeCMD(pb);

 return exeCmdStatus;
} //End doSomething Function

private boolean executeCMD(ProcessBuilder pb)
{
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 Process p = null;

 try {
  p = pb.start();

 } catch (Exception ex) {
 ex.printStackTrace();
 System.out.println("oops");
 p.destroy();
 return false;
}
// wait until the process is done
try {
 p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("woopsy");
p.destroy();
return false;
}
return true;
 }// End function executeCMD
} // End class WrapperExe
```

Comment: Estuve checando tu respuesta y los cambios que hice en tu ejemplo fueron estos:
```
String[] exeCmd = new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i", pathAudio, "-i", pathVideo ,"-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", out};
```

Basicamente lo que modifique fue el nombre de los archivos, puse los path donde estan ubicados losr archivos que quiero unir y el de salida, pero no me marca error y no me lo genera, no se si me puedas dar retroalimentación sobre como funciona lo que hace tu codigo.